# I'm passing a detached entity when saving to db using Hibernate Panache

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
final data class Event(
    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    var processingRequestId: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    @Column
    var processId: Long,
    @OneToMany(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "eventId")
    var results: MutableList<Result> = mutableListOf(),
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime? = null,
)

@Entity
@Table(name = "results")
final data class Result(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = -1,
    @Column(columnDefinition = "uniqueidentifier")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    var eventId: UUID? = null,
    @Column
    var resultKey: String,
    @Column
    var resultValue: String,
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column
    var createdAt: LocalDateTime? = null,
)
```

And a repository for events:

```
@ApplicationScoped
class EventRepository : PanacheRepositoryBase<Event, UUID>,
                        FetchEvent,
                        PersistEvent {
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EventRepository::class.java)

    override fun fetchById(id: UUID): Event? = find("processingRequestId", id).firstResult()

    @Transactional
    override fun save(event: Event) = Either.catch{
            persist(event)
            event
        }.mapLeft {
            logger.error("Error while persisting Event '$event'", it)
            DatabaseProblem.ErrorPersistingToDatabase(listOf("EventId = '$event'"))
        }
}
```

I'm using a test like this:

```
@QuarkusTest
class EventRepositoryTest {

    @Inject
    lateinit var eventRepository : EventRepository

    @Test
    internal fun `trying to save an event and being successful`() {
        val firstResult = Result(resultKey = "classification", resultValue = "passport")
        val secondResult = Result(resultKey = "docType", resultValue = "16")
        val thirdResult = Result(resultKey = "subType", resultValue = "32")

        val id = UUID.randomUUID()

        val testEvent = Event(
            processingRequestId = id,
            processId = 1L,
            results = mutableListOf(firstResult, secondResult, thirdResult)
        )

        val savedEvent = eventRepository.save(event = testEvent)

        println(savedEvent)

    }
}
```

Now when I run the test I get the following error:

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: domain.core.models.entities.Result

I've tried several things, but I keep getting this error. Only when I change the Cascade type to merge, I get a different error which is:

javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; statement executed: update results set eventId=? where id=?

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try using a Bidirectional @OneToMany, as shown in https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/